# How to use Google Contacts API via Oauth2 authentication

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, oauth-2.0

I have this below code to get calendar entries using the google Calendar API (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) which uses OAuth2.
It works well.

```
private IList<string> scopes = new List<string>();
private CalendarService calendarService;

private void InitializeCalendarService()
{
        // Add the calendar specific scope to the scopes list
        scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scopes.Calendar.GetStringValue());

        // Display the header and initialize the sample
        CommandLine.EnableExceptionHandling();
        CommandLine.DisplayGoogleSampleHeader("Google.Api.Calendar.v3 Sample");

        // Create the authenticator
        //FullClientCredentials credentials = PromptingClientCredentials.EnsureFullClientCredentials();
        var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);

        FullClientCredentials credentials = new FullClientCredentials();
        credentials.ClientId = "XYZ.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        credentials.ClientSecret = "XYZ";
        credentials.ApiKey = "XYZ";

        provider.ClientIdentifier = credentials.ClientId;
        provider.ClientSecret = credentials.ClientSecret;
        OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient> auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);

        // Create the calendar service using an initializer instance
        BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
        initializer.Authenticator = auth;
        calendarService = new CalendarService(initializer);

        CalendarList list = calendarService.CalendarList.List().Execute();
        // do something with the list .. the list is all good

} 

public IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient client)
{
        // You should use a more secure way of storing the key here as
        // .NET applications can be disassembled using a reflection tool.
        const string STORAGE = "google.samples.dotnet.calendar";
        const string KEY = "s0mekey";

        // Check if there is a cached refresh token available.
        IAuthorizationState state = AuthorizationMgr.GetCachedRefreshToken(STORAGE, KEY);
        if ((state != null))
        {
            try
            {
                client.RefreshToken(state);
                return state;
                // we are done
            }
            catch (DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException ex)
            {
                CommandLine.WriteError("Using an existing refresh token failed: " + ex.Message);
                CommandLine.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        // Retrieve the authorization from the user
        string[] array = new string[scopes.Count];
        scopes.CopyTo(array,0);
        state = AuthorizationMgr.RequestNativeAuthorization(client, array);
        AuthorizationMgr.SetCachedRefreshToken(STORAGE, KEY, state);
        return state;
}
```

How can I use the similar OAuth2Authenticator to fetch Contacts?

I am able to fetch contacts using the below code, but its not password-less, I need to get it working using Oath2. The example below uses Gdata contacts api v2. I can see that i can pass through  OAuth2Authenticator but im not exactly sure how to do it correctly (i cant see any valid examples in C# on the google site) and fetch the access code based on what the user is selecting.
I cant see how to use OAuth2Authenticator with the contacts api v3 (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)

```
RequestSettings rsLoginInfo = new RequestSettings("", email,pwd);
rsLoginInfo.AutoPaging = true;
ContactsRequest cRequest = new ContactsRequest(rsLoginInfo);

// fetch contacts list
Feed<Contact> feedContacts = cRequest.GetContacts();
foreach (Contact gmailAddresses in feedContacts.Entries)
{
        // Looping to read  email addresses
        foreach (EMail emailId in gmailAddresses.Emails)
        {
           lstContacts.Add(emailId.Address);
        }
}
```

Comment: A 'point' in the right direction comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897072/google-contacts-api-after-getting-the-access-token-oauth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up doing this by fetching the access code by having a browser control read the Document title value when the user selects the google account and grants access.

eg:

To Generate URL

```
RedirectURI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"

OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters()
{
    ClientId = clientId,
    ClientSecret = clientSecret,
    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
    Scope = requiredScope
};


// Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
string url = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
var loginUri = new Uri(url);

// This form has browser control
GoogleLoginForm form = new GoogleLoginForm(loginUri, redirectUri);
var dr = form.ShowDialog();

if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    parameters.AccessCode = form.OAuthVerifierToken;
}
```

Then In GoogleLoginForm :
We have a browser control and registered browserControl_Navigated event and the do the below. The DocumentTitle contains the AccessCode which is used to generate the token.

```
private void GoogleLoginForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   wbGoogleLogin.Url = _loginUri;
}

private void wbGoogleLogin_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    string fullPath = e.Url.ToString();
    WebBrowser control = sender as WebBrowser;
    if (control != null &&  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.DocumentTitle) && control.DocumentTitle.Contains("Success code"))
    {
       _OAuthVerifierToken = control.DocumentTitle.Replace("Success code=","");
       DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

This way it can be done in the same piece of code, without having to write a complicated callback service of some sort to read the access token back into our system.

Not exactly sure why the calendar api has this built in, and the contacts API doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the quick answer to your question. I believe that the IAuthorizationState has similar properties to OAuth2Parameters. Thus, you should be able to do this (combining it with the code you have for the calender):

```
OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient> auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);

//This will call your GetAuthorization method
auth.LoadAccessToken()
RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("appName", auth.State.AccessToken);
ContactsRequest cRequest = new ContactsRequest(settings);

// fetch contacts list
Feed<Contact> feedContacts = cRequest.GetContacts();
foreach (Contact gmailAddresses in feedContacts.Entries)
{
        // Looping to read  email addresses
        foreach (EMail emailId in gmailAddresses.Emails)
        {
           lstContacts.Add(emailId.Address);
        }
}
```

This should work as the RequestSettings allows you to specify an access token. That being said, I myself prefer to use :

```
var parameters = new OAuth2Parameters()
{
    //Client 
    ClientId = CLIENT_ID,
    ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET,
    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
    Scope = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds",
    ResponseType = "code"
};

//User clicks this auth url and will then be sent to your redirect url with a code parameter
var authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
.
.
.
//using the code parameter
parameters.AccessCode = code;
OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
var settings = new RequestSettings(applicationName, parameters);
var cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);
//Now you can use contacts as you would have before
```

Although, Ive only tested this with Web Server Apps, so maybe the authenticator is needed for your situation? I found these source codes handy:

[OAuth2Demo](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/clients/cs/samples/oauth2_sample/oauth2demo.cs)

[IAuthorizationState](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/blob/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client/OAuth2/IAuthorizationState.cs)

[OAuth2Authenticator](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Authentication.OAuth2/OAuth2Authenticator.cs?r=51be0b85b89c13ef9c4392f050b6eb2b91a99428)

Comment: this is correct, but this doesnt get the access code. I was wondering if there was a way to get the access code in the same piece of code easily.