# How to authorize console application c# for Google Contacts API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-contacts-api

I have an issue with the authorization in Google Contacts.
Until June my console C# application worked.

I have made steps to get contacts https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=en.
I cannot get the contacts; I have only access to serviceAccountEmail (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com).

I have 2 contacts stored there and I have access only to them.
I want to have access to my 7000 Gmail contacts.
Is there any tutorial for this in C#?
I found ones for analytics and for calendar but not for contacts.

Below is my code:

```
const string serviceAccountEmail = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2("grdom-all-xxxxxxxxxxxx.p12", "notasecret",
                X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer serviceAccountCredentialInitializer =
                new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = new[] { "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" },
                }.FromCertificate(certificate);

            var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(serviceAccountCredentialInitializer);
            if (!credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Access token request failed.");


            var oauthParameters = new OAuth2Parameters()
            {
                AccessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken,
                AccessType = "offline",
                ApprovalPrompt = "force",
            };

            var settings = new RequestSettings("grdom-all", oauthParameters)
            {
                AutoPaging = true,
                UseSSL = true,
            };
            ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);
            var query = new ContactsQuery(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
            Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
            foreach (Contact entry in f.Entries)
            {
                //do something
            };
```

Comment: Here is the link for accessing google contacts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264286/how-to-use-google-contacts-api-via-oauth2-authentication . Also you can check in the above link fro sample code in Running the sample code section. Let me know if you have any issues. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=en

Comment: The solution in the link that you gave me is for web application. I have console application. With my code i get the accessToken, but i cannot have access to gmail contacts. It is strange...

Comment: Did you configure your app to have access to Contacts in Google console? How about use "ready to use" libraries/services, like [CloudSponge](http://www.cloudsponge.com/integrations/net)?

Comment: No i din not yet. I need full rights in contacts, because every day the programm synchronize contacts from our company gmail accounts with crm. btw thanks to both of you (AST and Rael).