# Getting error with Google contacts API

Tags: vb.net, google-contacts-api

I made (in 2014) an vb.net app to retrieve all my contacts and it worked fine, now I want to use that app but I get this error: "Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 404"

This is the code I was using:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports Google.GData.Client
Imports Google.GData.Extensions
Imports Google.GData.Contacts
Imports Google.Contacts
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Xml

Partial Public Class _Default

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim rs As New RequestSettings("MYAPPNAME", "EMAIL", "PASSWORD")
    'Application Name,Username,password
    Dim cr As New ContactsRequest(rs)
    'Request all contacts
    rs.AutoPaging = True
    'Allow autopaging
    Dim f As Feed(Of Contact) = cr.GetContacts()
    'Get all contacts
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim dr As DataRow
    dt.Columns.Add("Name")
    dt.Columns.Add("Phone")
    dt.Columns.Add("EmailHome")
    dt.Columns.Add("EmailWork")
    dt.Columns.Add("EmailOther")
    dt.Columns.Add("Birthday")
    dt.Columns.Add("Address")
    dt.Columns.Add("URL")
    dt.Columns.Add("ID")
    'Get All Contacts
    For Each exi As Contact In f.Entries
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        Dim n As Name = exi.Name
        dr(0) = n.FullName
        Dim homeemail As String = ""
        Dim workemail As String = ""
        Dim otheremail As String = ""
        Dim homephone As String = ""
        Dim workphone As String = ""
        Dim otherphone As String = ""
        Dim birth As String = ""
        Dim address As String = ""
        Dim web As String = ""
        Dim contactid As String = ""
        'Extract Phone Numbers
        For Each ph As PhoneNumber In exi.Phonenumbers
            If ph.Other = True Then
                If otherphone.Equals("") Then
                    otherphone += ph.Value
                Else
                    otherphone += ","
                    otherphone += ph.Value
                End If
            ElseIf ph.Home = True Then
                If homephone.Equals("") Then
                    homephone += ph.Value
                Else
                    homephone += ","
                    homephone += ph.Value

                End If

            Else
                If workphone.Equals("") Then
                    workphone += ph.Value
                Else
                    workphone += ","
                    workphone += ph.Value

                End If

            End If
            dr(1) = workphone
        Next
        For Each email As EMail In exi.Emails
            If email.Home = True Then
                If homeemail.Equals("") Then
                    homeemail += email.Address
                Else
                    homeemail += ","
                    homeemail += email.Address
                End If
            End If
            If email.Work = True Then
                If workemail.Equals("") Then
                    workemail += email.Address
                Else
                    workemail += ","
                    workemail += email.Address
                End If
            Else
                If otheremail.Equals("") Then
                    otheremail += email.Address
                Else
                    otheremail += ","
                    otheremail += email.Address
                End If
            End If
            dr(2) = homeemail
            dr(3) = workemail
            dr(4) = otheremail
        Next
        Try
            birth = exi.ContactEntry.Birthday.ToString
        Catch ex As Exception
            birth = ""
        End Try
        dr(5) = birth

        For Each adrs As StructuredPostalAddress In exi.PostalAddresses
            If adrs.FormattedAddress <> "" Then
                If adrs.Equals("") Then
                    address += adrs.FormattedAddress
                Else
                    address += ","
                    address += adrs.FormattedAddress
                End If
            End If

            dr(6) = address

        Next
        For Each wb As Website In exi.ContactEntry.Websites
            Try
                web = wb.Href
            Catch ex As Exception
                web = ""
            End Try
            dr(7) = web
        Next
        Try
            If Len(exi.Id) = 85 Then
                contactid = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(exi.Id.ToString, 16)
            Else
                contactid = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(exi.Id.ToString, 15)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            contactid = ""
        End Try
        dr(8) = contactid
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
End Class
```

What changes I must do now to make it work again?

Thank you all.

Comment: It maybe that you are using oAuth 1.0 which was depreciated as of May 5, 2015. If that is the case you need to use oAuth 2.0 ...

Comment: Thanks Codexer. I went to google developers console and now I have my clientID and clientSecret but I dont know how to include them into the code, can you help me with that?

Comment: See this SO answer **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264286/how-to-use-google-contacts-api-via-oauth2-authentication**

Comment: I found a working example on: http://www.daimto.com/google-contacts-with-c/ but when I try to translate it to vb net I have a problem with "Dim credential As UserCredential" part. I have the error: "BC30652 a reference to assembly 'Google.Apis.Core, Version = 1.8.1.31685, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null' containing the type 'IDataStore' is required. Add it to the project" How can I translate this part?